# How to play video files containing mp4 extension in jmeter

Tags: video, jmeter, performance-testing, mp4

I have an application which has videos in mp4 extension.
I need to perform performance testing using jmeter. While recording the application in jmeter 5.1.1 am getting error as socket write error. So, I tried capturing it from fiddler and convert it to jmx.

Now am able to get 206 status code with partial content response on running in jmeter with blank response body.
How can I validate that I am getting the correct response against the mp4 request?
Is my approach correct ?
While running the developed script for multi user.System is getting hanged on executing the particular mp4 files.
How to overcome the same?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter cannot "play" mp4 files, it can only download them with [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

If you're getting [HTTP Status 206](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206) it means that the server responded with not the full .mp4 file but it rather delivered a part of it, you might want to check [Content-Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range) response header to determine which exact range of bytes did you get with this request. Going forward you can ask the server for the next part of the .mp4 file by sending the relevant [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) header using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

If you want to validate the response you can either save it as MD5 hash

[image]

and use [MD5 Hex Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) to compare the response hash with the expected one or go for [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener to store it to your local hard drive

Comment: Thank you so much for giving a right direction to my query. But am not clear on using MD5 hex assertion. How can I know what should be the MD5 hex value against which I have to compare my response hex value. I have no clue on what is the download file path of video. I am just a front end application user. For 1 complete video download it is getting captured in 3 https requests(different bit rates),so how to get the MD5 hex value for individual 3 requests for implementing assertion?